# Summing a random list of numbers in an i loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, sum

I've created a program that generates a list of numbers of users choice, between 1 and 500. The program then writes the list to a file, reads the file, and lists all the numbers. I need to sum the numbers and show the count. Here is my code...

```
numberFile = open("random_number.txt", "w" )

for i in range(int(input("How many random numbers?: "))):
   numbers = str(randint(1, 500))
   numberFile.write(numbers)
   print(numbers)


numberFile.close()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the summation happening ?  I come from a JAVA background and so I am not familiar with python syntax but I would expect some kind addition accumulation logic

Comment: 1) create another variable initially set to 0 and keep adding the values to it. 2) append the values in a list and use `sum(my_list)`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
However, if you follow whatever resources you find on line, make an honest coding attempt, and run into a problem, you'd have a good example to post.

Comment: Reading a file, converting to integers, and summing a list are all covered quite well on line.  Research first, then post.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your code.

```
numberFile = open("random_number.txt", "r" )
sum = 0
for i in numberFile:
    sum += int(i)

print(sum)
```

At first, sum is 0. The program reads each value and adds the value to sum.

Answer (score 0):

If you want <strike>pythonic</strike> cryptic code, you can do this in 2 * 2 lines (+1 line of import):

```
import random

# create file
with open("t.txt","w") as nf:
    nf.write( '\n'.join(map(str,random.choices(range(1,501),
                                               k=int(input("How many numbers?"))))))
```

The first one uses the inputted value, makes it an int, uses it as "how many" parameter to [random.choices()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) which returns as much random numbers from the given [range (1,501)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) which are then fed into [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to make them strings so [join()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) can make a big string of them wich is then written into the file.

```
# read / sum file
with open("t.txt","r") as nf:
    print(sum(map(int,(x.strip() for x in nf.readlines() if x.strip()) ) ) )
```

This reads the whole file as list of lines, strips the newlines, converts them into ints and sums them. (see [Doku built-in functions for int, map, sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) )

---

Outputting the generated stuff:

```
with open("t.txt","r") as nf: 
    print(nf.read())
```

Sum:

```
2371
```

Outputfile:

```
320
13
138
112
369
339
447
44
211
15
110
253
```